# Unable to restore table from snapshot in Redshift Serverless

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

Unable to restore any table in Redshift serverless using a snapshot. With the error returning:

```
ValidationException
Cannot perform table restore using this snapshot.
```

Tried to create snapshot from recovery points and tried to restore from provisioned cluster to serverless and create a serverless snapshot and both scenario still have the same issue.